# React Virtual Dom Diff resets Css Animation

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs

I am building a game, with css animations.

I have this css rule for move animation:

```
.animate {
  animation: play-move 1s steps(10) infinite;
}
```

I update my state every half second so state changes as:

1. State: `[0, 1, 0]`
   View: `<div/><div class="animate"/><div />`
2. State: `[0, 0, 1]`
   View: `<div/><div/><div class="animate">`

The problem is as the dom changes, the css animation resets, so I can't see the full animation.

see react version:

http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/12998/

However if you reverse the move direction, animation doesn't reset.

mithriljs version:
http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/12982/

jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/12968/

Comment: can you make fiddle for this?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I did.

Comment: No, it doesn't play the full animation, it plays only the half, i need the animation to continue seamlessly during it moves. @ParthTrivedi . PS: Change the `updateDuration` variable to `1000` to see the full animation play.

Comment: Can you do hide/show  your animated Div to avoid reset?

Comment: Why don't you use a `translate` animation, instead of updating the class attr of divs ?

Comment: @SébastienOllivier You are absolutely right. MOVING the div seems just the correct approach

Comment: @vals, I use [mithriljs](http://lhorie.github.io/mithril/), so i don't know how to render properly.

Comment: @user3995789 Sorry, I don't know this library, I can't help you

Answer (score 0):

instead of updating entire `DOM` you can just change `class` attr value as like fuddle link below.

http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/12974/

on render: you can render `<div class="tile temp100"></div>`.

on state change you can change the class as sequence as `temp100,temp010,temp001`

Comment: I have to add more tiles dynamically at specific positions? http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/12977/

Comment: so you want all tile as a different persons and you just want to show hide? and not as a moving one?

Comment: okay.. and you want hand position  to be continued where hand position when it was hiding?

Comment: I want to add a person at a position, and start moving it. While they move, I want its animation to work seamlessly.  I can add multiple person so they both move at the same time.

Comment: so to move you have to you have to use `position : absolute` and top & left to move. and don't re-render dom again and again & if you want to hide use css `display:none or visibilty:hidden` based on the situation.